# Upload CSV File In C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have got problem when I try to upload my csv file into Oracle Database in C#. The error message occured like this **{"ORA-00936: missing expression"}**. I have no idea to fix it. Does anyone here could help me to solve this problem please.

This is my current code;

```
conn.Open();

foreach(DataRow importRow in importData.Rows)
{
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO TMCI_PPC_IMPORTDATA_PSI (ITEM, REQUIREMENT, REQ_DATE)" +
                                          "VALUES (@Itm, @Req, @ReqDT)", conn);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Itm", importRow["ITEM"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Req", importRow["REQUIREMENT"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReqDT", importRow["REQ_DATE"]);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Several issues:

1. Oracle uses `:`, not `@` for parameters
2. You should create parameters *once*, before loop.

**Code:**

```
        ...
        conn.Open();

        // Oracle uses : not @ for parameters
        string query = 
          @"INSERT INTO TMCI_PPC_IMPORTDATA_PSI (
              ITEM, 
              REQUIREMENT, 
              REQ_DATE)
            VALUES (
              :Itm, 
              :Req, 
              :ReqDT)";

        //DONE: wrap IDisposable into using
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn)) {
          //DONE: create parameters once
          //TODO: validate parameters' types
          cmd.Parameters.Add(":Itm", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
          cmd.Parameters.Add(":Req", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
          cmd.Parameters.Add(":ReqDT", OracleDbType.Date);

          foreach(DataRow importRow in importData.Rows) { 
            // assign parameters as many as you want
            cmd.Parameters[":Itm"].Value = importRow["ITEM"];
            cmd.Parameters[":Req"].Value = importRow["REQUIREMENT"];
            cmd.Parameters[":ReqDT"].Value = importRow["REQUIREMENT"];

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
          }  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the parameters need to have : as a prefix not @

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO TMCI_PPC_IMPORTDATA_PSI (ITEM, REQUIREMENT, REQ_DATE)" +
                "VALUES (:Itm, :Req, :ReqDT)", conn);
```

And change your paramters to be like the following:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Itm", importRow["ITEM"]);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it's really work. I just knew it that in oracle is not using @ as parameters. Thank you very much all